# 5 Pin DIN to XLR/Jack for Old Old Old Microphones?

Tags: xlr, vintage, microphone, connector

I'm off to bed in a moment so just a quick one...

Has anyone ever come across any old pre-1950/60s mics using the 5 Pin DIN (5/180°) connections? (Or MIDI cable connections if that jogs the memory better). I've seen a few going pretty cheap and would love to get something out of them but am unsure how to connect them to a female XLR input. I'm hoping someone is aware of a male 5 pin din to male XLR adapter/connecter (preferably on a UK site but that's just wishful thinking ;]) or any method by which I could connect it to an XLR or 1/4" Jack input. I've had a quick look tonight but with rather fruitless results so far.

So if anyone has any knowledge on the subject they'd like to share please do :]
If I get desperate I guess I could always take the wire apart and go from there...

Cheers and Goodnight!

Comment: maybe it needs a power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Jamie may be correct about it needing a power supply. Most microphones that utilize more than three inputs do require a matching power supply. Another possibility is to do some research on the specific models you're looking at. If you can find information concerning the pinout, then you'll be one step closer to figuring out how to interface it with modern gear.

Another key element to consider is output impedance of the microphone. You may need some sort of buffer circuit between it and your gear (another function that those matching power supplies often provide).

Comment: You don't get to say that very often...(pinout)